# How to delete Named Ranges with Tab names via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, named-ranges

I'm trying to clean a spreadsheet of a slew of Named Ranges I no longer need, and leave behind the few I'm still using. All of these Named Ranges include the Tab name, because they originate on a template Tab (named **tmp**), from which other Tabs are duplicated. Even after I delete all the spinoff Tabs from the sheet and leave behind only **tmp**, the 'tmp'! appears in the names of the Ranges, both as displayed in the Named Ranges sidebar and as they come in on getNamedRanges().

When I try to selectively delete obviated Named Ranges, no matter how I spec the name of the Ranges, I get errors saying no such Named Ranges exist. Basically, I'm feeding back the same information getNamedRanges() and getRange().getSheet().getSheetName() give me, only to have it garbled along the way.

The problem is isolated in the following test snippet, and involves rendering the single quotes around the Tab name. I have tried several approaches, including escaping the single quotes with slashes, and have added to the code the Comments of the errors I got on the line **targetDoc.removeNamedRange(namedRange)**.

```
const analyzerDoc = '1pYgcX2dxzHd4cCofy0RFZTzEl36QesiakMGIqCC2QlY'
const openAnalyzerDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(analyzerDoc)


function testDeleteNamedRange (){
  var docUrl = openAnalyzerDoc.getRangeByName('docUrl').getValue();
  var targetDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(docUrl);
  // var namedRange = 'dyCl_MoodEntries'         // The named range "dyCl_MoodEntries" does not exist.
  // var namedRange = 'tmp!dyCl_MoodEntries'     // The named range "tmp!dyCl_MoodEntries" does not exist.
  // var namedRange = "'tmp'!dyCl_MoodEntries"   // The named range "&#39;tmp&#39;!dyCl_MoodEntries" does not exist.
  // var namedRange = "\'tmp\'!dyCl_MoodEntries" // The named range "&#39;tmp&#39;!dyCl_MoodEntries" does not exist.
  targetDoc.removeNamedRange(namedRange);
}
```

This bug is in the way of a longer function, which is working fine but for the part isolated in this test function.

The longer function gets the names and Tabs of Ranges to delete from this sheet: [image: Analyzer Doc]

What is the right way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer to my own question. There is probably more than one solution, but I have chosen to sidestep the challenge I am facing, and instead of specifying the Named Ranges by name, I am going to spec them by their position in the document's Named Ranges, and simply use remove() instead of removeNamedRange(namedRange). I had gotten so caught up in the recommended method involving forEach, that I had forgotten that the outcome of getNamedRanges() is not an object, but an array.

The solution then lies in amending my process of collecting the Names and other information from the result of getNamedRanges(). Instead of using forEach, I loop over the results of getNamedRanges(), and while I get the information I desire concerning each Named Range, I also log the loop iteration and thereby get the Index Number of each Named Range.

I proceed as before, pasting this information in a Tab where I can select which Ranges to delete.

My delete function then loops over the Named Ranges directly, in reverse order, and checks the loop iteration against the Ranges I have ticked off in that analysis Tab.

I have tested this in a sample document; you may view it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-R9zGn-rIvhlvohefWliXS0_ueu5Ukg-eKkSPEmei2U/edit?usp=sharing).

In this demo, all functions are within the same document, so I'm using getActive() instead of openByUrl.

This document has 3 Tabs named Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3. Each Tab has 3 Named Ranges named Moe, Larry and Curly. There is also a Tab NamedRanges which the following function collects Named Range into:

```
function getnamedRanges() {
  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges();
  var namedRangeData = [];
  for (i=0; i<namedRanges.length; i++) {
    var namedRange = namedRanges[i];
    var nrName = namedRange.getName();
    var nrRange = namedRange.getRange().getA1Notation();
    namedRangeData.push([nrName,nrRange,i])
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NamedRanges').getRange(2,1,namedRangeData.length,3).setValues(namedRangeData)
}
```

Here's the Named Range Tab after running that function, and choosing 3 Named Ranges to delete:

[image: Named Range Tab after collecting Named Range info and selecting NRs to delete]

Next, here is the function that removes the selected Named Ranges:

```
function deleteSelectedNamedRanges () {
  var namedRangeData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NamedRanges').getDataRange().getValues();
  namedRangeData.shift(); // Remove header row data.
  var rangesToDelete = namedRangeData.filter(function(nrDatum) {if (nrDatum[3]==true) return nrDatum});

    // [3] equivalates to Column D, the checkboxes where I select which Named Ranges to delete.
    console.log (rangesToDelete.map(value => value[0])); // [ 'Sheet3\'!Moe', 'Sheet2\'!Curly', 'Sheet1\'!Moe' ]
    console.log (rangesToDelete.map(value => value[2])); // [ 0, 1, 5 ] // [2] is the index number of the Named Ranges.

    /* The order here derives from how values in Tab Named Ranges happen to be sorted. 
    In this instance, I have not changed that order, so the Named Ranges To Delete are in ascending order.
    For one thing, this is the opposite of what we want; 
    for another, I want to be able to sort the Named Range Tab freely before making my selections.
    So, we must sort this data in DESCENDING order. */

  rangesToDelete.sort(function(value1,value2){if (value1[2]<value2[2]) return 1; if (value1[2]>value2[2]) return -1; return 0});

    console.log (rangesToDelete.map(value => value[0])); // [ 'Sheet1\'!Moe', 'Sheet2\'!Curly', 'Sheet3\'!Moe' ]
  var rangesToDeleteIndexNumbers = rangesToDelete.map(value => value[2])
    console.log (rangesToDeleteIndexNumbers); // [ 5, 1, 0 ]
  var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges();
  for (i=namedRanges.length-1; i>=0; i--) { 

    /* We must loop in descending order because deleting Named Ranges will change the index numbers
     of all Named Ranges that come after each we delete. */

    if (rangesToDeleteIndexNumbers.indexOf(i) !== -1) {namedRanges[i].remove(); console.log ('Removed NR # '+i)} 

    // Delete Named Range if this iteration number can be found in rangesToDeleteIndexNumbers.
  }
}
```

After running this function, you can see that the 3 Names Ranges have been removed, leaving 6 behind:

[image: After removing Named Ranges]

Comment: I just want to mention that after using this in the actual document, I deleted 41 Named Ranges at a go, and now the function that makes duplicates of that Tab tmp is running much faster! This, regardless of the fact that many of these Named Ranges had stopped being referenced in any formula for many revisions of this template. Evidently just creating Named Ranges by duplicating a Tab that contains Names Ranges takes a significant amount of time. So, deleting unneeded Named Ranges is good housekeeping, and not creating unnecessary NRs in the first place is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

#### This function will remove all of the named range that have their sheet name within the range name.

```
function deleteAllNamedRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getNamedRanges().filter(r => ~r.getName().indexOf(r.getRange().getSheet().getName())).forEach(r => r.remove());
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to remove ALL of the Named Ranges, just like 30 out of like 40. I have them all listed in a sheet with a column of checkboxes for selecting the ones to remove, and function to delete them all. It isn't working, so I made this little test function to isolate the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that they include the name of the sheet that they are found on?

Comment: Please  provide an image of your sheet with all of the names and check boxes.  Are you interested in doing this with an onEdit() trigger or a single function that runs once and does the job?

Comment: Yes. As you can see from my errors, there is no getting around speccing the Tab name (see first example.) Absolutely all of the NRs I want to remove have the Tab name. This holds true even when I delete all the tabs but the template from which they originate.

Comment: It's a single function. This is part of a redesign process, and I intend to use it a few times as I weed out references to Named Ranges. I don't see how to include a pic in a Comment, so I'll edit my OP.

Comment: In your errors what is the sheet name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239301/discussion-between-atiq-zabinski-and-cooper).